# Rubygems: You do not have permission to push to this gem

Tags: ruby, permissions, rubygems

I have developed a gem called `web_scraper`. When I am trying to publish it to rubygems.org I am getting below issue.

```
> You do not have permission to push to this gem. Ask an owner to add
> you with: gem owner web_scraper --add <email>
```

Here is the output of `gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/bhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/bhaskar/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/bhaskar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/bhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/bhaskar/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/bhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
     - /home/bhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/bhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin
     - /home/bhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin
     - /home/bhaskar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin
     - /home/bhaskar/.rvm/bin
     - /home/bhaskar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.3/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

```
I have proper rubygems account and API key also available.

How to resolve this issue?
```

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message tells you to do to solve the error?

Comment: An account named dsperansky already created a gem called web_scraper 5 years ago. https://rubygems.org/gems/web_scraper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gem name needs to be unused on RubyGems, you can use the search on https://rubygems.org/ to check whether the gem exists, in this case, it does, so you'll need to rename your gem to use a name that isn't in use.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the message:

> You do not have permission to push to this gem. Ask an owner to add
>   you with: `gem owner web_scraper --add <email>`

You need to ask the owner of the [`web_scraper` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/web_scraper) to add you as a developer to allow you to make updates to the gem.